# Problem saving an output c program in a file

Tags: shell

I am trying to make a script to save the output of a c program in a file.
The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
make clean all
./bin/output -a edit -e 0.05 -i dataset.fseq --k 3 --check > file.txt
```

The script returns the empty file, without the execution results.

Here is an example of a script execution:

```
~/candidat.v1$ sh test3.sh
rm -rf bin build
make --directory=alignment all
gcc -Wall -g -O3 -I.. -c edit_bpm_distance.c -o ../build/edit_bpm_distance.o
gcc -Wall -g -O3 -I.. -c edit_column.c -o ../build/edit_column.o
  ../bin/filters_benchmark -lm -lrt
[Benchmark]
=> Total.sequences        1000000
=> Time.Benchmark        14.90 s  (    1   call,  14.90  s/call {min14.90s,Max14.90s})
  => Time.Filter        523.99 ms (  3.52 %) (    1 Mcalls,    523 ns/call {min145ns,Max36.76us})
=> Check
  => TP.Hit       766954 (76.695)
    => TP.OK.IN   226477 (22.648)
    => TN.OK.OUT  540477 (54.048)
  => FP.Noise     233046 (23.305)
  => FN.Miss      0 (0.000)
```

file.txt should return a file with the execution results, but it returns an empty empty file.

Comment: How do you know there is any output to save?  Could you add to your question an example of running the script and what appears on the console?  And of running the program directly?  Finally could you clarify what is meant by "returns" in "The script returns ..."?

Comment: @ScottMcPeak When I run the program directly, appears de following output:              => Total.sequences        1000000
=> Time.Benchmark        14.96 s  (    1   call,  14.96  s/call {min14.96s,Max14.96s})
  => Time.Filter        525.75 ms (  3.52 %) (    1 Mcalls,    525 ns/call {min149ns,Max25.81us})
=> Check
  => TP.Hit       766954 (76.695)
    => TP.OK.IN   226477 (22.648)
    => TN.OK.OUT  540477 (54.048)
  => FP.Noise     233046 (23.305)
  => FN.Miss      0 (0.000)

Comment: @ScottMcPeak When I say "the script returns" I mean when the script is executed it generates an output file. And this one is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this program send the output to STDERR, not STDOUT. So you can rewrite the script to write STDERR in the same file:

```
#!/bin/sh
make clean all
./bin/output -a edit -e 0.05 -i dataset.fseq --k 3 --check > file.txt 2>&1
```